# How to check if XElement has any child nodes?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

I have the following condition,

```
if (myXElement.FirstNode.NodeType == XmlNodeType.CDATA)
```

This throws an exception if there is no `FirstNode` in `myXElement`, so I have to check first if there is any.

Note that I need to check for nodes not elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var hasDescendants = myElement.Nodes().Any();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the VB but wouldn't this work

```
    If myXElement.Nodes.Count > 0 AndAlso myXElement.FirstNode.NodeType = Xml.XmlNodeType.CDATA Then

    End If
```